# Microsoft Quantum Development Kit Symmetric key encryption

Tags: visual-studio, quantum-computing, q#

Is there any open-source Post-Quantum Cryptography (PQC) or Quantum Safe Symmetric cryptography algorithm available for Microsoft Quantum Development Kit

Answer (score 0):

You may find the https://github.com/microsoft/grover-blocks project from Microsoft Research of interest. That repository looks at cost estimates for many different components of AES, such as the SBox step, using the resources estimator provided with the Quantum Development Kit.

Answer (score 0):

PQC is different from Quantum Safe; though PQC can be a subset of Quantum Safe, because Quantum Safe is a broader concept and it can include Quantum Key Distribution.

It is the Asymmetric Key algorithms that we use today are under threat by Quantum Computer.

- So the PQC efforts as driven by NIST Standardization process focuses
  only on Asymmetric algorithms for  Key Exchange and Digital
  Signatures.
- Doubling the key size of today's Symmetric key usage
  will give such symmetric keys enough quantum resistance.

Microsoft QDK is to implement Quantum Computing algorithms - they have nothing to do with PQC. If you need symmetric key support then you can consider the C#. QDK based Q# Quantum Applications can integrate with C# for the Symmetric key encryption.

So QDK has not PQC support.